# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type') in redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Does anybody know why I get this error?
When I go to push the book object into the state array then shows this error.

Folder structure
[image: Folder structure]

**Here is my BookSlice code**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"


const initialState={
    books:[
        {id:"1", name:"Data Structure", author:"motalib"},
        {id:"2", name:"Structure", author:"hossain"},
        {id:"3", name:"Structure", author:"shamim"},
    ]
}

export const bookSlice=createSlice({
    name:"books",
    initialState:initialState,
    reducers:{
        showBook:(state)=>state,
        AddBooks:(state,action)=>{
            state.books.push(action.payload);
        }
    },
})

export const {showBook, AddBooks}=bookSlice.actions;
export default bookSlice.reducer;
```

**Here is my store code**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import bookReducer from "../Features/BookSlice";


const store=configureStore({
    reducer:{
        bookReducer:bookReducer
    }
})
export default store
```

**Here is my dispatch function**

when I go to dispatch the add book reducer then shows this error
[image: form]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import AddBooks from "../Features/BookSlice"

const AddBook = () => {
    const dispatch=useDispatch()
    const [book, setBook]=useState({
        id:'',
        name:"",
        author:""
    })

    const HandelChange=(e)=>{
        const {name, value}=e.target
        setBook((prev)=>{
            return{...prev, [name]:value}
        })
    }
    console.log(book);
    const HandleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(AddBooks(book))
        e.target.reset()
        console.log(book);

    }
return(
here is HTML form
);
};
```

Comment: You've a typo exporting an undefined action. `showBoo` should be `showBook`, e.g. `export const { showBook, AddBooks } = bookSlice.actions;`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Comment: yes, correct it.But still the same problem

Comment: `bookSlice.reducer` is the default export from `BookSlice`. You likely meant to import the ***named*** export `AddBooks`. You've still some typos.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo here

```
export const {showBoo, AddBooks}=bookSlice.actions;
```

It should be

```
export const {showBook, AddBooks}=bookSlice.actions;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
import AddBooks from "../Features/BookSlice"
```

should be changed to:

```
import { AddBooks } from "../Features/BookSlice"
```

That is, if you have a similar situation, when you do non-default export, you should use `{Curly brackets}` during import.